# Restoring Anaconda Environment

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I somehow deleted my only working tensorflow environment in the conda UI. The folder for it still exists in conda/envs but I can't find the .yml file to import it back.

Is there anyway I can save myself from hours of grief?

Comment: The environment no longer shows up when you do `conda info --envs` ? You were having issues when first setting it up?

Comment: Is there still an environment in the folder? or is it just stragglers (e.g., packages that were installed with `pip`)? If the full env is still there, `conda activate /path/to/the/envs/env_name` should work. Theoretically, one should be able to recreate a YAML of an environment with just the `conda-meta/history` file. Any chance that is still there?